# django updating user profile with custom form + display group name

Tags: django, authentication, django-forms, django-views

I've got 2 questions:

1) I'm displaying a list of users w/ their group,and for the group name I got: ]> using {{instance.groups.all}} in my template. Any ideas to have only mygroup displayed?

2) For my update user form, I got an error and I don't know how and where to resolve it.

error: updateUserView() got an unexpected keyword argument 'id'

forms.py

```
class UpdateForm(UserChangeForm):
    is_active = forms.BooleanField()
    Group = [('Viewers', 'Viewers'), ('Editors', 'Editors'), ('Creators', 'Creators'), ]
    group_name = forms.ChoiceField(choices=Group)

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('email', 'is_active', 'group_name', )
```

views.py

```
def updateUserView(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UpdateForm(request.POST, instance=request.user)
        if form.is_valid():
            user = form.save()
            group = Group.objects.get(name=request.POST.get('group_name'))
            user.groups.add(group)
            return redirect('accounts:users')
    else:
        form = UpdateForm(instance=request.user)

    return render(request, 'accounts/update_user.html', {'form': form})




class UserView(LoginRequiredMixin, GroupRequiredMixin, ListView):
        template_name = 'accounts/display_users.html'
        group_required = ['Creators']
        queryset = User.objects.filter(is_active=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

instead of using 
     group = Group.objects.get(name=request.POST.get('group_name'))
try using 
     group = form.cleaned_data.get('Group')

Comment: Using your suggestion, I'm getting this error now when I register a new user: django.db.utils.IntegrityError: NOT NULL constraint failed: auth_user_groups.group_id

Answer (score 0):

To solve the error `error: updateUserView() got an unexpected keyword argument 'id'`
you need to pass the id to the view. Because your url is probably like this `'/user/<int:id>/'`

```
def updateUserView(request, id):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        ........
```

Comment: You're right, now I have this error: 'int' object has no attribute '_meta'